# "Revert" one hot encoding

Tags: r

I have dataset where many variables are actually kind of "one hot encoded", and I would like to collapse it to have a single variable with the value.

```
  name  born_2017 born_2018 born_2019
  <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 Paul          0         1         0
2 Diane         0         0         1
3 Jose          1         0         0
```

And I want it to look like that :

```
  name  birth_year
  <chr> <chr>     
1 Paul  born_2018 
2 Diane born_2019 
3 Jose  born_2017
```

I watched around `dplyr` and `tidyr` but I somehow didn't find what I need.

ps: I have to do this for a lot of variables so an easily generalizable solution, or working with the pipe, would be very helpful

Comment: What happens to the "encoding". Is it just discarded?

Comment: @NelsonGon That's not the same problem, I don't want to get more row at the end.

Comment: As it's currently written, it's the same problem. What happens to the 0s and 1s?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gather`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  gather(birth_year ,flag , born_2017:born_2018) %>%
  filter(flag == 1) %>%
  select(-flag)
```

Comment: I thought about that but the fact I have to use a flag, adding many rows to the code since I have to do it for many variables, is quite boring

Answer (score 0):

```
example <- read.table(text = "
name  born_2017 born_2018 born_2019

 Paul          0         1         0
 Diane         0         0         1
 Jose          1         0         0", h = T)
```

In this particular example, this could as well work with just base R:

```
example$birth_year <- colnames(example[,2:4])[apply(example[,2:4], 1, which.max)]

example[,c("name", "birth_year")]
   name birth_year
1  Paul  born_2018
2 Diane  born_2019
3  Jose  born_2017
```

Based on Sotos suggestions, the following two approaches are vectorized, do not need `apply` and are more dense, and are therefore preferable:

```
subset(cbind(example[1], stack(example[-1])), values == 1)
```

or

```
 names(example[-1])[max.col(example[-1])]
```

Comment: There are vectorized ways to do it via base R that do not require `apply`. For example, `subset(cbind(df[1], stack(df[-1])), values == 1)` or following your thought, simply, `names(df[-1])[max.col(df[-1])]`

Comment: That is even way better indeed, thanks a lot :) I hope you don't mind I updated my answer